# Styled components props inside conditional props

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

My styled component code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";

import { theme } from "../shared/theme";

const ContainerDiv = styled.div`
    padding-bottom: ${props => props.theme.paddings.text.small};
    padding-top: ${props => props.theme.paddings.text.small};
    padding-left: ${props => props.theme.paddings.text.normal};
    padding-right: ${props => props.theme.paddings.text.normal};
    font-size: ${props => {
        if (props.bigLabel && props.bigLabel === true)
            return props.theme.typography.sizes.big;

        return props.theme.typography.sizes.normal;
    }};
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: ${props =>
        props.bold && props.bold === true ? "bold" : "normal"};
    ${props =>
        props.type &&
        props.type === "danger" &&
        `
        color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text.danger};
        `}
    ${props =>
        props.type &&
        props.type === "primary" && 
        `
        color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text.primary};
        `}
`;

class Text extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        href: PropTypes.string,
        bold: PropTypes.bool,
        paragraph: PropTypes.bool,
        type: PropTypes.string
    };

    render = () => {
        let { href, bold, paragraph, type } = this.props;

        let content = this.props.children;
        if (paragraph && paragraph === true) content = <p>{content}</p>;

        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <ContainerDiv href={href} bold={bold} type={type}>
                    {content}
                </ContainerDiv>
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    };
}

export default Text;
```

Using the `type` property is supposed to change the text color, but in my tests the desired color is not being applied:

```
<Text type="primary">Primary text</Text>
<Text type="danger">Danger text</Text>
```

In both cases the color remains the default one.

How do I properly set the text color according to my `type` property?

Comment: Can you create a more reproducible example removing the extraneous variables? Might also be with the `type` currently being passed, did you try with a static value?

Comment: Missed post formatting. Please posted example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `props` within a `${props =>` declaration, you do not need to also call the function in the inner function because you have access to `props` from the outer function call.

So this:

```js
${props =>
  props.type &&
  props.type === "danger" &&
  `
    color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text.danger};
  `}
```

would become this:

```js
${props =>
  props.type &&
  props.type === "danger" &&
  `
    color: ${props.theme.colors.text.danger};
  `}
```

notice how `color` is now `color: ${props.theme.colors.text.danger};` instead of `color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text.danger}`

Additionally I would consider another prop name instead of `type` because this will cause `type` to be rendered to the DOM in your HTML (because `type` is a valid HTML attribute).

---

Also on a separate note, you can safely just check for `props.type === "danger"` instead of checking for the existence of `props.type` first, the result is the same.

So `${props => props.type === "danger" && ...your styles`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap color into another function, you can get directly by type:

```
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text[props.type]};
```

Or if you need to check if `type` is defined:

```
  color: ${props => props.type ? props.theme.colors.text[props.type]: '#FFFFFF'};
```

Comment: This way will force color to be `#FFFFFF` in case of no `type` passed. I need it to keep the inheritated color...

Comment: Then change `#FFFFFF` to `inherit`, that was just for illustration.